# Cant replay video after finish playing

Tags: ios, swift, error-handling

I use following code to reveal two different video-sources as background. The "selectVideo" (`SegmentedControl`) is used to select video. The problem is down below.

```
@IBAction func selectVideo(sender: AnyObject) {
    if self.Controller.selectedIndex == 1 {
        self.videoBackgroundCustomer()
    }

    if self.Controller.selectedIndex == 0 {
        self.videoBackgroundDriver()
    }
}

    func videoBackgroundDriver() {
        //Load video background.
        let videoURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("background_video_2", withExtension: "mp4")!

        player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
        videoBackground()
    }

    //Video background customer
    func videoBackgroundCustomer() {
        //Load video background.
        let videoURL: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("background_video_1", withExtension: "mp4")!

        player = AVPlayer(URL: videoURL)
        videoBackground()
    }

    //Vieobackground-code part 2, provides with less code.
    func videoBackground() {
        player?.actionAtItemEnd = .None
        player?.muted = true

        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        playerLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill
        playerLayer.zPosition = -1

        playerLayer.frame = view.frame

        view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)

        player?.play()

        //call loop video
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(LoginViewController.loopVideo), name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: player!.currentItem)
    }

    //Loop video
    func loopVideo() {
        player?.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
        player?.play()
    }
```

**Problem: The video restarts when the last video should have ended. And not when the most recent video ends.**

How do I make it repeat playing after the last playing video finished? Thanks

Comment: method `seekToTime`'s return type is `void` not `CMTime`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After investigation of the problem firstly take a look at [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avplayeritem/1390153-seektotime?language=objc) and return values of the method.

```
- (void)seekToTime:(CMTime)time;
```

Method that you are using return `void` and could not be compared to the `CMTime`

For solving of you're problem try this solution:

First you need to subscribe you're class to the notification that will indicate that video is ended.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,selector: "itemDidReachEnd:",
    name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification,
    object: player.currentItem)
```

And than define method to handle this notification.

```
func itemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    player.seekToTime(kCMTimeZero)
    player.play()
}
```

In this case you are tracking when video ends and you start it again.

Comment: Somehow I got another bug now, I have updated the question. Thanks!